# nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, nginx, https

I ran these two commands separately:

```
openssl dhparam -dsaparam -out ./certs/dhparam.pem 4096

openssl req -x509 -nodes \
   -days 965 -newkey rsa:2048 \
   -keyout ./certs/nginx-selfsigned.key -out ./certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
```

I copied them to my NGINX server, and when I started NGINX I got:

> ```
> 2019/06/12 01:33:47 [warn] 1#1: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate
> ```
>
> "/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"
>       nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"

does anyone know what that's about? I don't see how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 11):

It's an SSL cert verification since you're using a self-signed cert this validation will not work.
  References:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04
2. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_stapling

   It shouldn't prevent your webserver to work properly

   Regards,

Comment: Is there a way to silence that warning?

Comment: Try `ssl_stapling off;`